# where is the Flash 10.3 playerglobal.swc?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I've downloaded the release version of the [Flex 4.5 SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.5) (4.5.0.20967), but it seems to be missing the 10.3 version of playerglobal.swc.

During the beta, I could go to the Adobe Labs site and get the beta playerglobal.swc, but the [link](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10-3.html) now says its no longer hosted there.

Where are we supposed to get the playerglobal.swc from, if not the SDK?

Comment: 10.3 was released yesterday I think; after the Flex 4.5 SDK came out.  Why do you need a 10.3 version of PlayerGlobal.swc?  I, personally, have never needed to much w/ the SDK.

Comment: Adobe's probably not gotten to it yet.  It did *just* get released...

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: there's a lot of new audio features in 10.3 that can only be accessed by having the 10.3 playerglobal.swc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thibault Imbert recently had shared the location of "playerglobal.swc" with a Flash community for Flash Player 10.3 in his [twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/thibault_imbert):

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer10-3/flashplayer10-3_playerglobal_052011.swc

Comment: True, "playerglobal.swc" for Flash Player 10.3 is now located at http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/playerglobal10_3.swc

Comment: update: Adobe keeps it here now http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Older versions can be found here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone (like me) is still looking for SWCs > 10.2 (latest version bundled with Flex SDK 4.5.1) - now Adobe is putting new SWCs at [Flash Player downloads page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) - you also can find [10.3 SWC](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/playerglobal10_3.swc) there.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get it from:

http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/playerglobal/playerglobal10_3.swc

Later versions can also be found here:

http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/11/playerglobal11_X.swc

Where X is in the range 0 to 9.

For later versions:

http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/12/playerglobal12_0.swc
http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/13/playerglobal13_0.swc
http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/14/playerglobal14_0.swc

Comment: I'm really surprised Adobe still uses the Macromedia domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here : http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/

Comment: Unfortunately that's the FP11 preview playerglobal, not the FP 10.3 release verison. :(